# Autocompletetextview dropdown list has artifacts with Android L

Tags: android, list, toolbar

I've replaced the actionbar in an application with a toolbar using Appcompat21 (as per Android L instructions). Everything works fine, except that when opening an autocompletetextview dropdown list from the toolbar we get strange symptoms. When scrolling up and down this list we see the following artifacts (see screenshot) that take up half the height of the toolbar.

The artifacts aren't aligned with the list that you're scrolling from - the artifact text is indented to the right by about half the width of the screen, but it is the same font size. The artifact is also obviously a separate element - in other words, scrolling to the upper end of the list shows the "end" highlighted in the usual way that android behaves when you try to scroll past the end of a list, and the artifact is still above that. When you scroll the list the artifact also scrolls at roughtly the same rate.

Note: I've modified the screenshot to get rid of proprietary info - so the smudged top half of the toolbar can be ignored (it's just there to show that the artifact reaches exactly halfway up the toolbar), and pretend that instead of the word LIST there's an actual scrollable list of things.

I'm not posting code because our code didn't change at all from Android pre-L to Android L, and only under L do we get these symptoms (the only change was the new toolbar). I'm primarily interested in whether anyone has encountered symptoms similar to these in other applications using Android L and the toolbar, and how they overcame such issues.

edit: the second screenshot shows the "static" box that you can get sometimes as an artifact (see on the lefthand side of the toolbar). I've tried to make it a bit easier to understand than the first one.

UPDATE:

when I tried to disable hardware acceleration for the entire application (in the manifest)

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

The artifacts disappear, but I still have a black bar appear over half the toolbar height instead (see third screenshot).

Comment: Did Hierarchy View or **`uiautomatorviewer`** indicate to you what your "artifact" is? Are you testing this on hardware or an emulator?

Comment: We've tested on hardware (two separate nexus 5 phones with android L) and we see the artifacts on both of them. When I run it on an emulator using Android L I don't see the artifacts

Comment: I'm trying to run heirarchyviewer now through ddms - I'll update on what I find

Comment: That won't work on hardware, unless you modify your code to add Romain's `ViewServer`. **`uiautomatorviewer`** will work on hardware.

Comment: Uiautomatorviewer doesnt recognize the artifact as a view at all. It just recognizes all the views that are around it. As far as the tool is concerned there are only two main views - the list and the toolbar. The artifact sits partways on both of them, and sometimes on just the toolbar (the static artifact)

Comment: That feels like something's busted in the hardware acceleration, then. I'm assuming from the screenshots that you don't have a reproducible test case that you can distribute. If you come up with one, let me know, as there's not much more that I can do without one.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't distribute the apk but I do appreciate the help, and it's given me a direction to explore. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a long time to figure this out so I'll post it for anyone else who encounters the same sort of problems. The issue turned out to be this line of code:

```
android:popupBackground="@color/white"
```

which, if gotten rid of, completely solved the whole artifact issue.